# Google app engine blob store video file storage and retrieval

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

Is it possible to upload a video file to blob store and then let the clients download the file locally and play form the local copy?

Comment: yes! It's just a file!

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/features/#blobstore There are links to python, java, and go.

Since you did not specify a language I will show you the example for webapp2 and [python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Serving_a_blob). The example says photos but the same code will work for any blob since it does not explicitly send content type headers.

```
import webapp2

from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

# A custom datastore model for associating users with uploaded files.
class UserPhoto(ndb.Model):
  user = ndb.StringProperty()
  # blob_key = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()
  blob_key = ndb.BlobKeyProperty()


class PhotoUploadFormHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload_photo')
        # The method must be "POST" and enctype must be set to "multipart/form-data".
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
        self.response.out.write('<form action="%s" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">' % upload_url)
        self.response.out.write('''Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br> <input type="submit"
            name="submit" value="Submit"> </form></body></html>''')

class PhotoUploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        try:
            upload = self.get_uploads()[0]
            user_photo = UserPhoto(user=users.get_current_user().user_id(),
                                   blob_key=upload.key())
            user_photo.put()

            self.redirect('/view_photo/%s' % upload.key())

        except:
            self.error(500)

class ViewPhotoHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self, photo_key):
        if not blobstore.get(photo_key):
            self.error(404)
        else:
            self.send_blob(photo_key)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', PhotoUploadFormHandler),
                               ('/upload_photo', PhotoUploadHandler),
                               ('/view_photo/([^/]+)?', ViewPhotoHandler),
                              ], debug=True)
```

Comment: This link doesnt talk about how to "download a blob store file from clients "

Comment: I will update the answer once OP tells us which language he is using.